# How to replace dots with commas in multiple csv files?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have semicolon delimited CSV file. Some numerical values are stored with decimal point, for other data manipulation I need to use numbers with decimal comma. This should run for each file in the same folder on any Win machine. Any ideas?

I have tried `PowerShell` successfully on single file using this script

```
(Get-Content VER_ZdnSort201608-20160908210028original.csv) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "\.", "," } | VER_ZdnSort201608-20160908210028new.csv
```

But I can't seem to get it work with multiple files, also without replacing content without creating new files.

The data looks like this:

```
520100;2016-08-31;3197.90;N0401
520200;2016-08-31;6406.66;N0401
520430;2016-08-31;536.40;N0401
520800;2016-08-31;1547.70;N0401
...
```

Output should be like this:

```
520100;2016-08-31;3197,90;N0401
520200;2016-08-31;6406,66;N0401
520430;2016-08-31;536,40;N0401
520800;2016-08-31;1547,70;N0401
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will search in a given folder for `.csv` files. It will then replace any `.` with `,` in all `.csv` files found, overwriting the new text to the same file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Folder -Filter '*.csv' | ForEach-Object {  
    (Get-Content $_.FullName).Replace('.',',') | Out-File $_.FullName 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following script constitutes a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for %%F in (%*) do (
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('
        type "%%~F" ^& ^> "%%~F" rem/
    ') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        >> "%%~F" echo(!LINE:.=,!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Provide the paths to your CSV files as command line arguments. Supposing the script is named `convert-decimal-point.bat` and your CSV files are located in `D:\Data`, use this command line:

```dos
convert-decimal-point.bat "D:\Data\*.csv"
```

---

Here is a comprehensive solution that does not blindly replace every `.` by `,` but checks each field whether it truly contains a fractional number (an optional sign `+`/`-`, followed by any number of decimal digits, followed by `.`, followed by any number of decimal digits; for example `1.2`, `-.73`, `+12.584`) or an exponential number (a fractional number, followed by `E`/`e`, followed by a sign `+`/`-`, followed by one or more decimal digits; for example, `1.2E-02`, `-.73e+5`). This is the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SEARCH=." & rem // (decimal point to search for)
set "_REPLAC=," & rem // (decimal point for replacing)
set "_SEPCHR=;" & rem // (field separator character)

rem // Predefine global variables here:
set "$HEADER="  & rem // (set to something to ignore first line)

for %%F in (%*) do (
    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('
        type "%%~F" ^& ^> "%%~F" rem/
    ') do (
        set "COLL=%_SEPCHR%" & set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "LINE=!LINE:"=""!^"
        if "!LINE:**=!"=="!LINE!" (
            if "!LINE:?=!"=="!LINE!" (
                for %%I in ("!LINE:%_SEPCHR%=" "!") do (
                    endlocal
                    set "ITEM=%%~I"
                    call :PROCESS ITEM ITEM
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    for /F "delims=" %%C in (^""!COLL!!ITEM!%_SEPCHR%"^") do (
                        endlocal
                        set "COLL=%%~C"
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
            ) else set "COLL=%_SEPCHR%!LINE!%_SEPCHR%"
        ) else set "COLL=%_SEPCHR%!LINE!%_SEPCHR%"
        set "COLL=!COLL:""="!^"
        >> "%%~F" echo(!COLL:~1,-1!
        endlocal
        set "$HEADER="
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  rtn_string  ref_string
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "#RET=%~1"
set "STR=!%~2!"
if not defined $HEADER (
    if defined STR (
        if "!STR:%_REPLAC%=!"=="!STR!" (
            set "CHK=!STR:*%_SEARCH%=!%_SEARCH%"
            set "CHK=!CHK:*%_SEARCH%=!"
            if not defined CHK (
                rem // Adapt regular expressions as needed:
                (echo("!STR!" | > nul findstr /R ^
                    /C:"^\"[0-9]*\%_SEARCH%[0-9]*\" $" ^
                    /C:"^\"[+-][0-9]*\%_SEARCH%[0-9]*\" $" ^
                    /C:"^\"[0-9]*\%_SEARCH%[0-9]*[Ee][+-][0-9][0-9]*\" $" ^
                    /C:"^\"[+-][0-9]*\%_SEARCH%[0-9]*[Ee][+-][0-9][0-9]*\" $" ^
                ) && (
                    set "STR=!STR:%_SEARCH%=%_REPLAC%!"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
for /F "delims=" %%S in (^""!STR!"^") do (
    endlocal
    set "%#RET%=%%~S"
)
exit /B
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seems to work, it makes Excel triing to open CSV, but no conversion happens

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command :

```
$file = Get-Content c:\somewhere\file.csv |Out-String

$file.Replace(".",",") |Out-File c:\somewhere\file.csv
```